# Proving inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, derivatives

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function and  let M, N, and P be the least upper bounds of |$f$(x)| |$f'$(x)| and |$f''$(x)| respectively prove that the square of N can never exceed 4 MP. I thought about using Taylor's theorem, but I do not know how to manage it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an idea. Given $h > 0$ and $t \in \Bbb R$, Taylor's theorem gives $$f(t + h) = f(t) + hf'(t) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}h^2$$ for some $\xi \in (t,t+h)$. This implies $$f'(t) = \frac{f(t + h) - f(t)}{h} - \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}h.$$

So

$$|f'(t)| \le \frac{2M}{h} + \frac{Ph}{2}.$$

Since this inequality is true for all $h > 0$ and $t \in \Bbb R$,

$$N \le \inf\left\{\frac{2M}{h} + \frac{Ph}{2} : h > 0\right\} = 2\sqrt{MP}.$$

Therefore $N^2 \le 4MP$.